# Modal popup in grid view not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i have a modal popup extender, link button (tempalte field), fake button in grid view. the target control id for mpe is fake button, popup control is a panel having another grid to dispaly details of the main request. i am calling mpe show method in link button click event but its not showing up. please help as i coudld not find solution though researched.
plese find my mark up an code.

Select operation in this grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDULead" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
 Caption="AMT Team Approval Details" CellPadding="3" CssClass="Grid"
 Height="75px" Style="left: 122px;
 position: absolute; top: 342px" Width="792px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Transition Request Number" OnRowCommand="grdDULead_RowCommand">
 <FooterStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="GridFooter" />
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="grDULeadlnkSelect" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" OnClick="grDULeadlnkSelect_Click" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="SelectRow">select</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;

     <asp:Button ID="btnfake" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ForeColor="Red" Text="Fake" Visible="False" />
                <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnfake" PopupControlID="pnlCDAMTClar" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                  </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

---

### Popup control markup

---

Code-behind
link button click (tempalte filed)
 protected void grDULeadlnkSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        lblReqno.Text=clickedRow.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
        ModalPopupExtender mpeTemp = ((ModalPopupExtender)(clickedRow.FindControl "ModalPopupExtender1")));
          mpeTemp.Show();
    }
```

Comment: debug your code and see what you get in mpeTemp. First confirm that it is not null.And one more thing why you are using modelpopextender for each row of gridview?

Comment: http://techbrij.com/772/show-modal-popup-edit-aspdotnet-gridview best way to do. I had implemented and it works fine.

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender pce = e.Row.FindControl("PopupControlExtender1") as AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender;

Comment: put your button only in template field give the command argument as id and command name to button eg: my button : <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddActivity" Text="Add Activity" class="btnNext" CommandName="AddActivity" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SNO") + ";" + Eval("OneFee") %>' runat="server"></asp:Button>

Comment: and on row command  protected void GridViewActivityGroup_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "AddActivity")
            {  HyperLinkActivity.Visible=true;ModalPopupExtenderActivity.Show();
            }}

Comment: here is my extender:   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkActivity" runat="server" Text="" NavigateUrl="javascript:void(0);" visible ="false"></asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderActivity" runat="server"
                        DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="HyperLinkActivity" PopupControlID="DivActivity"
                        CancelControlID="CloseActivity" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopup">
                    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

Comment: DivActivity contains a grid, which is bind every time the event fired for particular details of given id

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest not to continue with above code as you used, Because instance of ModelPop Extender created for each row which will decreases performance.

You can use a alternative solution as:

1.Keep Facke button inside gridview as you already did.

2.Remove ModelPopup Extender from Gridview and keep it outside of Gridview. Also add a fake linkbutton as below:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkFake" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"     TargetControlID="LnkFake" PopupControlID="pnlCDAMTClar" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

3.At server side, on click of your button show ModelPop as below:

```
ModalPopupExtender1.Show()
```

Hope this will help you, Let me know if you have any concern.